# Xcode's archive validation error "Missing Info.plist value" for a "Hello world" project

Tags: xcode, validation, archive

I'm able to reproduce the errors with an untouched ["Hello world" proj](https://github.com/alodotad/test-1) created from Xcode (`File -> New -> Project`). I then follow some instructions, making suggested changes, as seen below, from google search, but the same problem occurs:

1. Expand AppIcon set to include `All sizes` for iOS.
2. Add `Icon Name = AppIcon` to Info.plist.

Below are the errors:

> Asset validation failed
> Missing Info.plist value. A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'alodotad.test-1'. Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key. For more information see http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7. (ID: b9c6bcae-6ea1-4343-b173-e2c3c71f2ec9)

> Asset validation failed
> Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0. To support older versions of iOS, the icon may be required in the bundle outside of an asset catalog. Make sure the Info.plist file includes appropriate entries referencing the file. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface (ID: 02055686-c98c-4823-8041-9a77e46af895)

Xcode: Version 15.2 (15C500b)

Based on my understanding, I already have the key `CFBundleIconName` in `Info.plist`, and that my `AppIcon` file has `120x120.png` icon. What else do I need to check?

Comment: What steps did you take to create the "untouched Hello World" project? Start with Xcode -> File -> New. Then what steps did you take? Please put that info in the question. Do not reply in a comment.

Comment: Updated the question to include the steps that I took to create the project. Thank you.

Comment: And so what's the question? Just like the error message says, you have no icons. You can't validate without icons. You can build and run and so forth, but when it comes to archiving and validation, you have to fulfill some basic requirements, including having icons.

Comment: Explicitly added the question.

Comment: You _say_ you have an app icon, but in the online project that you posted, that's not the case. You need to add icons of the various required sizes in the asset catalog.

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstanding. I thought by selecting `Single Size`, `Xcode` will internally generate all the necessary sizes using `1024x1024` icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a solution

1. In the `Info.plist` file, add key `Icon Name`, with the value of `AppIcon`.
2. Select the icon file, `AppIcon`, and then in the Inspector (on the right), for the `iOS` option, change from `Single size` to `All sizes`.
3. Generate icon files for the reported missing sizes, and copy them to `AppIcon.appiconset` folder. You can go to this folder by right-clicking the name of `AppIcon` in the listing of `Assets` entry (in the `Project` navigator). Then modify the JSON file, `Contents.json` (also in the same folder) to include the entries for the new icon files.
4. Create a new archive and validate again, `Product -> Archive` (Clear the build folder if needed). It should work now.

I've pushed the changes to the github repo, ["Hello world" proj](https://github.com/alodotad/test-1).